# asp.net route parameter issue

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am working on a project of asp.net web forums.

I am using Routing in `global.asax`.

I am sending **username** in the parameter like `http://abc.com/DailyUsernameReport/fahad` it work fine with it but when i send the parameter like `http://abc.com/DailyUsernameReport/fahad.mahmood` it gave me an error.

Here **fahad** and **fahad.mahmood** are usernames which i am sending.

The error is:

`"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."`

Any username have "." in it gave error how can i overcome this problem?

The Global.asax value are :

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Reports_Daily_ByUsername", "DailyUsernameReport/{Name}",     "~/Reports/UNReportsDaily.aspx");
 routes.MapPageRoute("Reports_Daily_ByUsername_Month", "DailyUsernameReport/{Name}/{Month}", "~/Reports/UNReportsDaily.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Reports_Monthly_ByUsername", "MonthlyUsernameReport/{Name}", "~/Reports/UNReportMonthly.aspx");
 routes.MapPageRoute("Reports_Yearly_ByUsername", "YearlyUsernameReport/{Name}", "~/Reports/UNReportYearly.aspx");
```

Comment: Can you share a little bit of global.asax where you're re routing the requests?

Comment: yes i have shared the global.asax file content

Comment: If you google for "asp.net mvc dot in route parameter" you will find several questions on stackoverflow. Have you tried the solutions suggested on those pages?

Comment: Yes i tried all but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Route constraint to accept the names like abc.xyz see the msdn article for more details h [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#adding_constraints_to_routes)

e.g.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Reports_Daily_ByUsername",
        "DailyUsernameReport/{Name}",
        "~/Reports/UNReportsDaily.aspx",
        true,
        new RouteValueDictionary 
            {{"Name", "^[a-z]+\.?[a-z]*$}
       );
```

The regex I've created will accept "Abc" and "Abc.xyz" as valid names for routing.

Comment: It gave an error on Regular Expression that "Bad Compile request".